# Black and grey clouds in Texture Paint

Tags: texturing

I am trying to use the Texture Paint feature in Blender, but for some reason, the Clouds texture has black too, I'm following blender guru's tutorial, but cant get only white clouds. How do I fix this?[image: 1]

Comment: yes it doesn't work as it should, maybe pack your image and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: oh ok, I have never used that before so should I just paste it? https://pasteall.org/blend/a0880b13903e463eb51545f4eab367f1

Comment: could you please pack the images before sharing? (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend)

Comment: in the file you shared the Texture was enabled, not the Texture Mask, it looks like what you want is Texture Mask, maybe you confused the 2, it would explain your problem, even though in your screenshot you've enable Texture Mask, so what did you use?

Comment: i used texture mask. i just tried texture to see what will happen

Comment: please share pack the image and share the file at the exact same step as the one you are before painting

Comment: hey I changed some stuff and now it's working properly. i used my backup donut. it was working fine then. thanks though.

Comment: Ok maybe it was what i was talking about? Anyway...   ;)

Answer (score 0):

On your brush settings click on the *Blend* options, its probably on *Mix*, set it to *Overlay* and that should fix it.